# Forcing file download after clicking button on Play Framework

Tags: java, javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm currently working on a project with `Play Framework` (with `Java` Controllers) and I'm trying to force browser download of `.txt` and `.xls` files after clicking a button and getting information from a controller. Although I form correctly both types of files, I haven't found the way of forcing its download yet.
After hours of deep investigations, I've managed to call the controller by `Javascript` via `JavascriptRoutes` and `Ajax`, but I can't force its download, albeit i could put the `.txt` content in a div (which loads correctly).

This is what I have now:

```
function exportText(){
  jsRoutes.controllers.User.generateText().ajax({
    success: function(data) {
      $('#testDiv').html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error!")
    }
  })
}
```

(*exportText()* is called when a button is clicked)

```
public static Result generateText() {
    response().setContentType("application/x-download");  
    response().setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=test.txt"); 
    return ok(generateTXT("test.txt"));
}
```

(*generateTXT(String)* retrieves a `File` file)

Any help would be really apreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT**

the *javascriptRoutes* method looks like this:

```
public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
      Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
        // Routes
        controllers.routes.javascript.User.generateText()
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could it be that it should be "Content-Disposition" and not "Content-disposition"?

Comment: Still the same response! Maybe I'm not correctly "downloading" the file once the `Ajax` part succeeds... Thanks though!

Comment: Aha, didn't think about the js code, have you tried just setting window.location to the export url (you can get it from the jsroutes-object) instead of calling it with ajax?

Comment: Yep, tried but no effect :-( Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I realised Javascript was pulling our legs too much, so i decided to do it "Scala Way" like this:

**View**

```
@form(routes.User.generateText()){
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Export as .txt"> 
}
```

**Controller**

```
response().setContentType("application/x-download");
response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.txt");
return ok(generateTXT(numbers, "test.txt"));
```

(As i said in my question, *generateTXT(String)* retrieves a `File` file)

Thanks!